# как поместить в переменную >

Tags: cmd

Пытаюсь поместить в переменную знак >

```
set a=>
set a=%>%
set a=^>%
```

эти и много других комбинаций перепробовал ничего не получилось, переменная либо пустая либо выдает ошибку. как такое можно провернуть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В принципе, чтобы поместить в переменную `>` достаточно такого:

```
set a=^>
```

Но при использовании она станет частью команды, а это не то, что ты хочешь. Поэтому в переменную надо поместить `^>`, чтобы в момент вывода стрелка была экранированная:

```
set a=^^^%
echo %a%
```